# React Native Expo app stuck on SplashScreen when running production version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm a React Native beginner. When I build my app with `expo run:ios` I can run it in the iOS simulator with `expo start --dev-client` without problems.

However, when I try run the production version with `expo start --no-dev --minify` it gets stuck on the SplashScreen in the simulator. Same happens if I produce an .apk file with `expo build:android` and I try to install it on an Android device.
No error message is displayed on the console.

[image]

The `App.js`:

```
import { firebase } from './src/firebase/config'
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { LoginScreen, HomeScreen, RegistrationScreen, SettingsScreen, ZplashScreen, TestScreen, TestVideocall } from './src/screens'
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'

if (!global.btoa) {  global.btoa = encode }
if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {

const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    usersRef
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get()
      .then((document) => {
        const userData = document.data()
        setUser(userData)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error)
      });
  } else {
    setUser(null)
    setLoading(false)
  }

});
}, []);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
});

const HomeNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {props => <HomeScreen {...props} userData={user} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
      </>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

const SettingsNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name="SettingsScreen"  component={SettingsScreen} options={{ title: 'Settings' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="TestScreen" component={TestScreen} options={{ title: 'Test' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="TestVideocall" component={TestVideocall} options={{ title: 'Test Videocall' }} />
      </>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


const MainContainer = () => {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
              { user ? (
                  <Tab.Navigator>
                    <Tab.Screen name="HomeNavigation" options={{headerShown: false}} component={HomeNavigation} />
                    <Tab.Screen name="SettingsNavigation" options={{headerShown: false}} component={SettingsNavigation} />
                  </Tab.Navigator>
              ) : (
                  <Stack.Navigator>
                    <>
                      <Stack.Screen name="Login" options={{headerShown: false}} component={LoginScreen} />
                      <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
                    </>
                  </Stack.Navigator>

              )}
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      { loading ? (
        <ZplashScreen style={{ flex: 1}} />
      ) : (
        <MainContainer style={{ flex: 1}} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Please notice that I renamed the custom `SplashScreen.js` to `ZplashSchreen.js` due to a test to check if there was a conflict with a module named in the same way.

Here also my `expo diagnostics` output:

```
 Expo CLI 4.12.1 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 11.5.2
      Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 15.4.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 7.0.15 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 15.0, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 13.0/13A233 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^42.0.4 => 42.0.4
      react: ^16.13.1 => 16.14.0
      react-dom: ^16.13.1 => 16.14.0
      react-native: ^0.63.4 => 0.63.4
      react-native-web: ^0.17.2 => 0.17.2
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 4.12.1
    Expo Workflow: bare
```

Comment: Can you post your entry js/ts file?

Comment: do you mean the App.js?

Comment: Yes, the App.js.

Comment: Can't see something crucial wrong. Check if imports raise an issue by remove them.
Try to implement a minimal sample with just views instead of screens.
Try add witdh and height
```<ZplashScreen style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', height: '100%'}} />```

Comment: ok, I will try to cut out screens and run a few tests. I will post an update, thanks